# call onchange function inside onchange function javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i wanna to check `item_price` after click on particular `item_code` through `ajax`.In `item_rate` field if user gives price enter more than available price than i will show error message. ***"@Enter price under "this" available price"***. Both `item_field` and `item_rat`e calls `"onchange()"` `function`.
i have two different input fields with `onchange()` method.

**One** is `"item_code"` and **Second** is `"item_rate"`

i want to call `item_code` `onchange(`) `function`  ***inside the*** `item_rate` `onchange()` `function`.

```
<input type="text"name="item_code" id="item_quantity" onchange="item_code(this.value)">

<input type="text"name="item_rate" id="item_rate" onchange="item_rate(this.value)">


function item_code(code_value){
       function item_rate(rate_value){
    }
    }
```

thanks for  answers this question.

Comment: Does not make any sense why you would need to do this. Why would the function be nested?

Comment: The item_rate function being nested, it would not be available for the inline binding

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve but it looks like you are confusing scope, declaration and call. Could you be more clear by giving more details about why you want call `item_code` inside `item_rate`, what you want to do ?

Comment: i wanna to check `item_price` after click on particular `item_code` through `ajax`. if in `item_rate` field if user gives price enter more than available price than i will show **error message**. "@Enter price under "this" available price". 
Both `item_field` and `item_rate` calls `"onchange()"` `function.`

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `.trigger()`  method to trigger the event on the second item:

```
function item_rate(code_value){
    $("#item_code").trigger("change");
}
```

This will execute the function you assign as a listener.

Answer (score 0):

ON my opinion why don't you do this?

```
  <input type="text"name="item_code" id="item_quantity" onchange="myfunction()">

    <input type="text"name="item_rate" id="item_rate" onchange="myfunction()">

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function myfunction(){
         var subtotal=parseFloat($('#item_rate').val())*parseInt($('#item_quantity').val());
         alert(subtotal);
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your item_code function just call on change method on item_rate element.

Also use oninput rather than on change method.

```html
<input type="text" name="item_code" id="item_quantity" oninput="item_code(this.value)">

<input type="text" name="item_rate" id="item_rate" onchange="item_rate(this.value)">

<script>

    
 function item_rate(rate_value){
       console.log(rate_value);
 }

function item_code(code_value){
   console.log(code_value);
   var element = document.getElementById('item_rate').onchange();
}
</script>
```